# Proving $|A\cdot B|\leq \|A\|\|B\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, inner-products

[image]

I have been reading *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang and cannot follow his proof of this property of norms of vectors. In particular, he introduces $c$ as a component of $A$ and $B$ and then define $c$ as if it is a projection of the vector. Why is this the case?

Comment: He constructs a right angle triangle that has the side length $cB$ and hypotenuse $A$.

Comment: Can you offer a cleaner proof for this property?

Answer (score 0):

In the proof, the vector $\mathbf A$ can be thought of being composed of two components---one parallel to $\mathbf B$ and one perpendicular to $\mathbf B$, thereby forming a right-angled triangle. The vector sum of these two components is equal to the original vector $\mathbf A$.

Now that we have a right-angled triangle, we can apply Pythogoras theorem.

[image]